# Help solving this nonlinear first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(y')^2=y^2 f(x)+1$$
I know that $y'',y'\gt 0$ and $y$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$. I tried doing an asymptotic analysis where the 1 is trivial so we can take the square root of both sides and then $y=e^{\int \sqrt{f} dx}$. But how do I fix this solution so that it solves the original equation?

Comment: I tried using Wolfram Alpha on a simple case ($f(x) = x$), and it failed to solve it. Are you sure this problem is tractable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something like this.  Rewrite the equation as
$$ (y')^2 = y(x)^2 f(x) + \epsilon$$
and consider solutions of the form $$y(x) = y_(x) + \epsilon y_1(x) + \epsilon^2 y_2(x) + \ldots$$
where 
$$ y_0 = \exp(\int f(x)\; dx)$$
is a solution of the equation for $\epsilon = 0$.  From the coefficients of the higher powers of $\epsilon$, 
$$\eqalign{2 y_0' y_1' &= 2 y_0 y_1 f(x) + 1 \cr
2 y_0' y_2' + (y_1')^2 &= (2 y_0 y_2 + y_1^2) f(x) \cr
2 y_0' y_3' + 2 y_1' y_2' &= (2 y_0 y_3 + 2 y_1 y_2) f(x) \cr
}$$
etc.  Note that the $i$'th equation is a first order linear equation in $y_i$, so it may be solved using integrals.
Thus you get a series solution for $y(x)$ in powers of $\epsilon$.  I don't know if this converges at $\epsilon = 1$; that may depend on $f$.

Comment: thank you, how did you know to use that approach? Does this method have an official name that I'm not aware of, where could I learn about it?